# jQuery :not selector not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal I have created and attached a button to remove it when clicked. Twitter bootstrap's modal has functionality which closes the modal only when the close button or the background (the greyed out layer behind the modal) is clicked.

Wouldn't this work?

jQuery:

```
   $('#overlay:not(#modal)').on('click', function(e) {
       $('#overlay').remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

This is my modal `HTML`code:

```
<script id="Belief" type="text/html">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="modal-container">
                        <div id="modal" class="modal-animation">
                            <p>This is the {{avonValues}} template, We are actually passing data in once place the year: {{year}}! <br>


                                <a id="appButton" class="button button-primary modal-button">lets get started!</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: selector says.... target specific ID that isn't another ID.... doesn't make sense

Comment: `$('#overlay:not(#modal)')` does not impact what comes after it at all, other htan what elements are selected. the :not will not indicate to the event that it should ignore events that start from #modal. That's not how it works. There's nothing you can do to that selector that will make it work the way you want.

Comment: `$('#overlay:not(#modal)')` means select the element with the ID of overlay that does not have the ID of modal. And that makes no sense.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your helpful input!

Comment: Glad i could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work because :not(#modal) doesn't impact what elements the event can be triggered on in this case, since #modal isn't in the collection of elements generated by #overview.

jQuery selectors are for one thing: selecting elements. They do not affect any of the methods that are chained after it other than what elements were initially selected.

For what you want, you'll have to test the event target to see if it is #modal or a child of #modal.

```
$('#overlay').on('click', function(e) {
  // don't target #modal or any elements within #modal
  if ($(e.target).closest('#modal').length === 0) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

---

Look at it this way: The chain you created in your question works step by step:

```
$("#overview:not(#modal)")
```

The above selects the element that has an ID of `overview`, and doesn't have an id of `modal`.

```
.on('click', doSomething);
```

The above code binds a click event to the selected elements from the previous link in the chain.

Now, if you changed the first to `$("#overview")`, it will have the same result because all we did was remove *"and doesn't have an id of `modal`."*, which has no effect because an element that has an id of `overview` cannot have an id of `modal`, at which point you should be able to see why adding `:not(#modal)` didn't make the event ignore clicks originating from inside #modal.

Comment: Thanks for your help in the end, but your solution blocks the event on the button. I suppose this can't be done since the button is nested in the `#modal` div.

Comment: That is correct. you would have to further filter it (the if conditional) to allow the button but continue to block everything else. but... i don't know what you're doing with the button so i'll leave that to you.

Comment: Yeah I don't think an event like:  `div#1 > div#2 > div#3 > button` 
Have only div#1 or button remove the whole `modal` experience because they're nested.